# Find $g^{-1}(x)$ in terms of $f^{-1}(x)$ if $g(x)=1+f(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find $g^{-1}(x)$ in terms of $f^{-1}(x)$ if $g(x)=1+f(x)$

I find it hard to operate inverse functions.
So can anyone show me a detailed process?

Answer (score 2):

Start with $f(x)=g(x)-1$ and apply $f^{-1}$ to get

$$x=f^{-1}(g(x)-1)$$

Now set $y=g(x)$ this gives $x=g^{-1}(y)$ and replace in the above to get

$$g^{-1}(y)=f^{-1}(y-1)$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: let $y = g(x)$, so $x = g^{-1}(y)$. Can you use your equation to solve for $g^{-1}(y)$?

Comment: I get $f(x)=f(g^{-1}(y))=g(x)-1$ Can't go any further...

Comment: You should also replace $g(x)$ with $y$ and then solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is $g(g^{-1}(x)) = x$.  So we solve for $g^{-1}(x)$ in terms of $x$.  Somehow, it is easy and less confusing if we use the notation $y = g^{-1}(x)$ and solve $x = g(g^{-1}(g(x)) = g(y)$ and solve for $y$ (which is actually $g^{-1}(x))$.

So $x = g(y)$; what is $y$?

$x = g(y) = f(y) + 1$.  (we must "unwrap" the y.  First by getting rid of the "+1)

$x = f(y) + 1$

$x - 1 = f(y)$.  (Now we must "unwrap" the f(y); well the "un-f" is $f^{-1}$)

$x - 1 = f(y)$

$f^{-1}(x - 1) = f^{-1}(f(y)) = y$.  (And we're done!)

$g^{-1}(x) = y = f^{-1}(x - 1)$.  That's it!

Let's verify this really worked:

$g^{-1}(g(x)) = f^{-1}(g(x) -1) = f^{-1}(f(x) + 1 - 1) = f^{-1}(f(x)) = x$.  (Works in one direction.)

$g(g^{-1}(x)) = g(f^{-1}(x -1)) = f(f^{-1}(x -1)) + 1 = (x -1) +1 = x$ (Works both directions.  We're good.)